# Syntax Error in Insert query while using airflow MySqlOperator

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I am loading a `.csv` file into **mysql** table (test1 having 2 int columns) using `MySqlOperator`, but getting syntax error at insert query,below is code I am trying

```
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
            if str(filename).endswith('.csv'):
                     csv_data = csv.reader(file(filename))
                     for row in csv_data:
                            sql1=("""insert into test1 values (%s,%s)""",row)
                            mysql_op = MySqlOperator(task_id='testop',
                                       sql=sql1,
                                       mysql_conn_id='hack5_id', owner='hack5',dag=dag)
                            mysql_op.run(start_date=datetime.now(), end_date=datetime(2018, 5, 21))
```

ERROR:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '%s,%s)' at line 1")
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following:

```
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if str(filename).endswith('.csv'):
                 csv_data = csv.reader(file(filename))
                 for row in csv_data:
                        sql1="insert into test1 values ({})".format(",".join(row))
                        mysql_op = MySqlOperator(task_id='testop',
                                   sql=sql1,
                                   mysql_conn_id='hack5_id', owner='hack5',dag=dag)
                        mysql_op.run(start_date=datetime.now(), end_date=datetime(2018, 5, 21))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @kaxil, I tried above, both your code and my gives the same error,
actually the query it was building was like

```
insert into test1 values (['7', '8']),
```

populating list as it is, which we can see a wrong insert syntax.
so I modified the insert statement as below

```
sql1="insert into test1 values ({})".format(",".join(row))
```

which is building query as

```
insert into test1 values (7, 8)
```

and inserting without error.

Comment: Glad it helped at some point. Thanks I have updated my answer to reflect that.